# Calculate $P(\bar{X} < \epsilon)$ given that for all $i=1,2,...,n$, $P(X_i < \epsilon) > 1 - a$, $X$ is taken from some distribution $D$ and $0<a<1$

Tags: probability, inequality

My goal is to find whether we could end up with something in the form $P(\bar{X} < \epsilon) > 1 - b^n$ where $n$ is the amount of data points we have

Comment: I assume, but would like to clarify, that here $\bar{X}=\frac{X_1+\dotso+X_n}n$, i.e. is the sample mean of data $X_i$, yes?

Comment: @LoveTooNap29 Yes Absolutely! Sorry for the confusion

Comment: ${P(\bar X < \epsilon) = P(\sum_i X_i < n \epsilon) \ge P( \cap X_i < \epsilon ) = \prod_i P(X_i < \epsilon) > (1-a)^n}$

Comment: @ZangMingJie, This is what I got as well. My current goal is to find a result whose limit would tend to 1, not 0.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but you did not provide enough condition to get you a definite answer for that.
We need the full probability distribution function in order to calculate that.

To illustrate my point, here are an examples that both satisfy your condition but gives you different answers to your question.

$$
P_1(x) = \left\{ 
\begin{aligned}
    1-a \quad & \text{when}\quad  x=0 \\
    a \quad & \text{when}\quad x=2\epsilon \\
\end{aligned}
\right. 
$$
$$
P_2(x) = \left\{ 
\begin{aligned}
    1-a \quad & \text{when}\quad  x=\epsilon/2  \\
    a \quad & \text{when}\quad x=2\epsilon \\
\end{aligned}
\right.
$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could you elaborate on why these two examples give different answers?